Does Judges 13:21-23 show that G-d took flesh or that he appeared as angel?
In Judges 13:21-23, describes the angel of the Lord appearing to Manoah and his wife, who had been visited previously to announce the birth of their son, Samson, but in the verse the angel of the Lord is called G-d does this mean that G-d somehow took flesh or the form of an angel?

Please CEASE AND DESIST from making new accounts here.

You’ve made other accounts on this site before. We know your game. Missionaries don’t work. Imbeciles like you have been trying to spread lies and misgivings to us for millennia, and we’re still here. Doing things like this is entirely ineffective except at annoying people. So, “Connor”—I doubt that’s your name—get off your screen and do something productive.

Also, most of the lies you’ve posted on this site with your past accounts have been based on deliberate mistranslations of the original Hebrew. You should learn Hebrew. That alone might turn you from Christianity.

No it does not.

Goodness no. Please check your translation carefully. The narrator keeps telling us it's an angel. Then Samson's father (who doesn't seem to be the most astute) says we will die because we saw Elohim. The mother responds: "if G-d (Adonai) wanted to kill us, He wouldn't have shown us all of this." That means God showed the parents something by sending them an angel. Similarly it doesn't say "He wouldn't have told us this", but rather "He wouldn't have made us hear [Heb. hishmi-anu] all of this." Again, this means God sent an angel.
Okay so what's Manoah talking about? Same thing as the angel who wrestled with Jacob in Genesis 32:29. Elohim in both places either means "an angel of God", or simply "a divine being." (There are other contexts where Elohim can mean "deities", i.e. little-g gods; or even "the authorities.")

Mahari Kra actually is most detailed here: if we are not supposed to die, because the angel did not show us his (mission) (i.e. his name?) and went in flames to heaven. And also he would not give us news that we will have a child who will bring us salvation from the Pelishtim.
